# JAX-WS - wsimport tool not creating web service client correctly

Tags: java-8, jax-ws, webservice-client, wsimport

**jdk 1.8.0_151**

**macOS High Sierra - Version 10.13.2**

I'm trying to create a web service client using JAX-WS wsimport tool, it's throwing warning messages for web operation (ex:getOrderSummary) like,

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "getOrderSummary": more than one part bound to body

and ending up not generating Service agent (extending javax.xml.ws.Service) and an Endpoint class , so there is no way for me to invoke the web operations.It generates individual class files in soap body though.

What could be the problem? Is the endpoint not properly developed? Or am I missing something? I have used wsimport tool to create many clients earlier and no issues, only this endpoint is creating troubles. I tried with axis2 as well, instead of throwing warning, it throws error and stops. But it works in SoapUI.
[image]

For understanding purposes, I just included the warning message to do with web operation 'getOrderSummary'.

Command used to create client:

```
wsimport -extension -keep -p com.webservice -XadditionalHeaders http://localmc:7000/api/IntegrationWebServices/api/IntegrationWebService?wsdl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may probably due to TIBCO's new BW engine, which is exposing the web service. Unfortunately, the solution is to go back to Axis to create the client. I simply used Eclipse to generate client, Eclipse by default provide axis runtime to generate client.